# Sprinkling in AngularJS into existing jQuery heavy application

Tags: jquery, grails, angularjs

I have a jQuery heavy application written in Grails 2.2.0.  A large piece of the application is a single page app and what I've basically been doing up to this point is pulling in the required HTML into a `DIV` via `$.load()`.

I'm starting to add some AngularJS to the app because I think I'd eventually like to replace the majority of pure jQuery with AngularJS but I'm hitting an issue.

If I include the script tag to pull in AngularJS in the main layout file and then the page I want to perform some AngularJS functionality on is pulled in via `$.load()` at some point, AngularJS doesn't seem to bootstrap itself.

However, if I put the script tag that pulls in AngularJS in the HTML fragment that is being pulled in via `$.load()` it works fine.

Is there a reason for this that I don't quite understand about AngularJS yet?  The test code I'm using is quite simple, and it can be viewed in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QD7Nk/).

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="attributeApp">
    <div ng-controller="AttributeCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="master.name" />
        <div>{{master.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("attributeApp", []);

app.controller("AttributeCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.master = {
        name: "some name"
    };
});
```

Comment: If you're using $.load() you need to bootstrap your application manually - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/LufmNlNSxBM/s0ygHJGaOQYJ

Comment: Trying things from that discussion.  Keep getting TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'compile'.

Comment: Also, that post is 2 years old and I can't find that version of compile() in the angular docs. So I wonder if it even should work anymore.

Comment: Looks like bootstrap() is what I need now.  Just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get your jsFiddle to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/sYPqn/

Here is the js that I modified to get your bootstrapping scenario to work:

```
angular.module("attributeApp", [])
.controller("AttributeCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.master = {
        name: "some name"
    };
});

console.log("Angular: %j", angular);
console.log("ra: %j",  rootApp);    
angular.bootstrap(rootApp, ['attributeApp']);
```

I removed the ng-app="module" part in the DOM because I think it isn't necessary and it is also potentially confusing. I replaced it with a named div id and bootstrapped the app based on the id of the element.